# How to envoke a method on a react component (Amcharts-React)

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

Is there a way to evoke a method on a chart. Such as:

```
chart.zoomOut()
```

I'm struggling to find a handle for the chart object. 
To render the chart i use:

```
<AmCharts ref={`chart_${this.props.tileid}`} {...this.chart} dataProvider={this.props.data} />
```

https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-react

I tried to inspect the element to see if I can access these methods through:

```
ch = this.refs[`chart_${this.props.tileid}`]
```

However in the 'ch' object I can not seem to find any of the methods mentioned in:
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomOut

How would one reference a element to evoke a method on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amchart3-react component sets the chart as a state. Thus the method can be evoked by calling:

```
this.refs.chartref.state.chart.zoomOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to talk to the maintainers of amCharts3-react. The wrapper component library could have defined the component to accept as property an event-handler that is called when the wrapper's `componentDidMount` method has been called, so that the event-handler can grab an instance of an object that the wrapper component is a container of.

Example:

```
// Note, this is just a hypothetical property. It will not actually do anything
// when applied to your code.
<AmCharts onChartRendered={chart => this._amChart = chart } {...props} />
```

But it seems like the author of the wrapper did not define the component to accept any such property, and therefore there isn't any way for you to invoke any methods from amCharts.